# Azure App Service 502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, http-error

I have simple azure service app that talks to azure storage tables . This works just fine when I run it through visual studio and gives the below error when I run it after deployment .

Server error 
502 - Web server received an invalid response while acting as a gateway or proxy server.
There is a problem with the page you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed. When the Web server (while acting as a gateway or proxy) contacted the upstream content server, it received an invalid response from the content server.

•   This use to work just fine a few months before .
•   I have no Azure application gateway or proxy , I believe its mandatory to have one right ?
•   The problem is there in both http://myservice.azurewebsites.net/Add/Create and http://www.myservice.com/Add/Create
•   There is some data base interaction that happens before the problem page comes.  I also see that that data interaction on the problem page also completes fine , as I can see from backend that the data has been added.
•   Using application insights , I see that all the said actions returned https error 200 , none have 502 .

I see from some web search , this is some front end error , what logs in azure will tell me the details ?

Comment: Have you tried to [Enable diagnostics logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log) for your web app? Could you show the related code in your backend? Moreover, you could [Remote debugging web apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio#remotedebug), [Troubleshoot HTTP 502 & 503](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-troubleshoot-http-502-http-503) by yourself to narrow down this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@BruceChen Thanks a lot , those are great links , Putting System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("My Info") in my code  , i was able to see in the real time trace logs ; that I had an exception in my code :( . Fixing the exception fixed the error .